# Best way to manage users without a DB

Tags: javascript, html, parsing

I'm building a simple webapp for a local company looking for a way to manage the shifts of their 10 employees and to quickly check them from anywhere.

For tests sake I've used a plain txt file uploaded into a page manually and a basic parser to retrieve users (employees) and their data but, for obvious reasons (security breaches), I'm looking for a way to manage these data without having to resort to a DB since it'd be a waste of resources for just 10 employees.

Any idea is welcome :D

P.S.: I'm actually using js scripts but I don't mind using PHP or any other language if it means reaching the goal

Comment: A text file isn't the worst idea as long as you handle it well i.e encryption, access control and back-ups.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways,

1. You can store user details in .json file hosted on S3 bucket and access it via S3 public URL or CloudFront Signed URL.
2. Hard code the all 10 users details in Static JSON/XML file within your web app source bundle (Not recommended).
3. User Any Cloud database (dynamoDB, mariaDB etc.) and access it via Lymda function. (most recommended)

Answer (score -1):

Since you are only storing the users names and time of shifts, I would use JSON file format to store this information. You could also encrypt any sensitive data, but if you are going to be storing passwords and other sensitive data then maybe you should use a Database.

Comment: not going to store passwords nor any other sensitive data, just shifts and names/surnames. Well shouldn't json files behave like a txt too when it comes to security breaches? I mean you can't even use them to test locally because any browser will stop the execution of the script...

Comment: Well yes they behave like a txt file, its just a text format to assist with readability and can be easily modified because they have key/value pairs rather than a txt just storing bulk. When it comes to security you can just encrypt the values.

Comment: the problem is that browsers won't let you use files from local storage. I need to try and put it somewhere in a cloud storage service

Comment: @Leon - are you going to be copying html/js/css files to computers and running your page using `file:///` protocol - rather than http/s? How are they going to `quickly check them from anywhere` if you don't have a web server somewhere?

Comment: @Bravo no wait maybe I didn't put it out clearly: obviously the "db" file would go to the webserver where I'll host the entire webapp :)

Comment: @Leon - oh,ok - the fact you were lamenting having to get cloud storage made me think you were doing it wrong :p